# Can I filter outlinks by anchor or title in stormcrawler?

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I looked at the JsoupParserBolt code, anchors are added after outlinks passed filter. Is it true that if I want to filter out links by text/anchor, I have to extend JsoupParserBolt and add anchor to metadata before the link goes through filter? Is there any other way to filter urls without changing java code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Great question, thanks! You could create a ParseFilter to filter the outlinks. They have access to a [ParseResult](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/parse/ParseResult.java) object which has get/setOutlinks() methods. Your custom ParseFilter should be able to implement the filtering logic. Worst case, you could discard the existing outlinks and reparse the doc using the documentFragment.